# How to apply a formula to all rows without for loop in R?

Tags: r

I have a column with values as follows and I want to take 1 random value between "+or_"20% of the same value of each row and assign it to another column.

sample_data

```
    benchmark
1   100
2   200   
3   250
4   400
5   150
6   1000
```

Now I want to create a variable called value in the same data by adding 1 random number between +or- 20% of the benchmark value for each row.

Expected output:

```
    benchmark   value
 1  100         87 
 2  200         213
 3  250         255
 4  400         320
 5  150         180
 6  1000        900
```

The snippet below illustrates my attempt to achieve that; it works as expected, but takes too much time to get executed:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(sample_data)){
    sample_data$value[i] = sample_data$benchmark[i] + runif(1,min = -0.2*sample_data$benchmark[i], max = 0.2*sample_data$benchmark[i])
}
```

How can I improve upon the performance of my code?

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
sample_data$value <- runif(length(sample_data$benchmark), 
                            min = 0.8 * sample_data$benchmark, 
                            max = 1.2 * sample_data$benchmark)
```

Comment: please try to understand the question.... the code u suggested me will generate n row of samples.... which is of no use... any how thanks

Comment: The code will generate 1 random value between 80% and 120% of the benchmark value in the same row. I believe it gives exactly what you have asked for.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
sample_data %>% mutate(value = benckmark + (benckmark * runif(1, -0.20, 0.20)))
```

Tested on

```
sample_data <- tribble(~Benckmark, 100, 200, 250)
```